# getIntger() -> getLong()?

Tags: android, long-integer

I use Android Studio.

For example if "int" is like this.

```
<integer name="test_int">1</integer>

getResources().getIntger(R.integer.test_int);
```

If so, how do you program "long"?

```
<long name="long_test">1L</long>
```

Comment: long not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct API available to read `long` from `strings.xml`. You can retrieve it as follows:

```
final String longTestString = getResources().getString(R.string.long_test);
final long longTest = Long.parseLong(longString);
```